# Search Value from anywhere in Dataframe and get location of that value and update it

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to search value 'Apple' in DataFrame and update these value to 'Green Apple'

My method is search location of that value and update it.

My code below

```
x = df[df.isin(['Apple'])].stack()
```

It return Row Index and Col Name as I expect, but I don't know how to get these value

```
6  Fruit Name    Apple
dtype: object
```

I try get value 6 (Row) and Fruit Name ( Col )

x[0] or x.value but it does not work

And besides if Value has spaces like `'    Apple'` it also not work.

There are any syntax like "islike" instead of "isin"?

Answer (score 0):

For finding location of the element you can use the same method `df[df.isin(['Apple'])].stack()` and for replacing the element in whole dataframe you can use `df.replace()` as given below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['Apple', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'Apple']})

new_df = df.replace('Apple','Green Apple')

print(new_df)
   A  B            C
0  0  5  Green Apple
1  1  6            b
2  2  7            c
3  3  8            d
4  4  9  Green Apple
```

Reference

[pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)